# set accessible does not make the private propery accessible when used it mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, mockery

I am tying to mock a class to test it. It has a `private property` `detail` which is set by a network request. I am trying to set the `property` before testing other `methods` by mocking a `json file`. Everything is working fine except, I cannot seem to set the property when it is a private property but works when it is a protected property.

```
$mockedClass = \Mockery::mock( Myclass::class )->makePartial();
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($mockedClass);
$property = $reflection->getProperty( 'detail' );
$property->setAccessible(true);
$property->setValue($mockedClass, $jsonData );
```

so when `detail` is a `private property` it Mockery throws a `Property detail does not exist` but when I make `detail` protected, it works.

I do not want to make `detail` a `protected property` because it does not need to be but I am needing to make it so to test it.

As I read somewhere "Like you mother said, do not expose your privates". I do not want to expose my privates.

Comment: you missed single quota after "'detail"

Comment: @RaghavRangani my bad, fixed it.

Comment: after still your issue??

Comment: @RaghavRangani it that was my issue, i would not get other errors I mentioned, I would just get missing quotes error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making this slight change:

```
$mockedClass = \Mockery::mock( Myclass::class )->makePartial();
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(Myclass::class); // Pass the class name, not the actual mock object
$property = $reflection->getProperty( 'detail' );
$property->setAccessible(true);
$property->setValue($mockedClass, $jsonData );
```

Comment: Not sure why I did not try this but worked like a charm. thanks